# Can't fetch all record from Mysql-PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that simply fetch data from my database, this query returns 590 rows.
When I put the SAME query, untouched in PHPmyAdmin, it returns overs 1000 records.

I have tried to write the query in other ways, changed from mysql to mysqli, the result is the same. I can't get all the record that I need.

`SELECT invoice_orders.invoice_number, invoice_orders.ddt_number, invoice_orders.date, invoice_order_products.productcode, invoice_order_products.category, invoice_order_products.amount, invoice_order_products.price, invoice_order_products.composizione`

`FROM invoice_orders, invoice_order_products`

`WHERE invoice_orders.id = invoice_order_products.invoice_id
AND FROM_UNIXTIME( invoice_orders.date, '%m/%Y' ) = '01/2011'`

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're querying the same host and db schema/table?

Comment: emmm, I have changed the host for connecting to the database, from localhost to the ip number, and now it works. I'm going to ask if there was a migration that I wasn't aware...many thanks

Comment: I'm just happy to help :) Check you hosts file. Maybe you have an entry association that hostname to a different IP

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing elements of the query - remove from_unixtime and check you get consistent results - then add your filters...

I might suggest instead of saving timestamps that you use a datetime field - but that's just personal preference.